# React native Dropdownalert with Navigation not working together in Redux Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm using react-native-dropdownalert and navigation. Both referenced using ref in App.js and working just fine.

```
          <AppNavigation
         ...
            ref={navigatorRef => {
              NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
            }}
         ...
          </AppNavigation>
          <DropdownAlert 
          ...
            ref={ref => {DropDownHolder.setDropDown(ref)} }
          ...
```

However while using in Saga they doesn't wont to work together. Once alert displayed using DropDown then navigation never happens. I was trying to use both yield put and call but result was the same.

```
export function* someAsyncSaga({ params, api, constant }) {
  try {

    // api = Api.someCall in that case
    const response = yield call(api, params)

//    "some_call_success"
    yield put({
      type: constant.SUCCESS, payload: response
    });

    if (response['Status'])  {


        yield put(DropDownHolder.getDropDown().alertWithType(
          'success',
          '',
          'Alert showing just fine',
      ))

        // But navigation never happens
        yield put(NavigationService.navigate('SomePage'))                  

    }
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, 'error')
    yield put({
      type: constant.ERROR, payload: error
    });
  }
}
```

But if I'm using componentDidUpdate which I assume as a bad practice I able to see alert and do navigation.

```
    // Lifecycle methods
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

if (this.props.Order != prevProps.Order) {

                    // Alert showing just fine
                    DropDownHolder.getDropDown().alertWithType(
                      'success',
                      '',
                      'Alert showing just fine',
                    )
                    
                    // Navigation happens just fine
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('SomePage')

            }

    }
```

And what I especially I even able to do navigation and then display alert.

```
if (this.props.Order != prevProps.Order) {
                    
                    // Navigation happens just fine
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('SomePage')


                    // Alert showing just fine after navigation
                    DropDownHolder.getDropDown().alertWithType(
                      'success',
                      '',
                      'Alert showing just fine',
                    )


            }
```

However with saga I only available to do navigation or DropDownAlert, but not together.
How can I use both DropDownAlert and navigation in my saga?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with how I was using NavigationService in my saga. Actual error was `put(action): argument action is undefined` and solution to that issue is to call NavigationService that way:

`yield call(() => NavigationService.navigate('SomePage'))`

Answer was found on github https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/840#issuecomment-450278415